# Linking CSS stylesheet serves wrong file

Tags: html, css

I have a weird/frustrating problem. I'm trying to link my CSS stylesheet to my HTML and when I check in the Chrome dev tools what the file looks like live (rather, why my styling isn't working), I'm getting an entirely different file showing as my .css file.

Here's my file directory:

```
- app
  - public
    - file1.html
    - file2.html
- assets
  - style
    - reset.css
    - style.css
```

And here's the head of file1.html:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/style/reset.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/purecss@0.6.2/build/pure-min.css" integrity="blahblahblah" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/purecss@0.6.2/build/grids-responsive-min.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/style/style.css">
```

The last line is my relative path.

The contents of file2.html are showing up as the contents of style.css when I look at it through dev tools, but all that really is in style.css is some styling for the h1 element. Am I just being a dummy with the relative file path for the CSS file? I thought maybe the other CSS stylesheets were impeding this style sheet, but commenting them out still results in the contents of file2.html as my css file. What am I missing?

Comment: The path seems to be correct. Are you absolutely positive no other stylesheet is loaded afterwards and that the reset.css file has no properties marked as !important? Using !important overrides all priorities. Additionally, I would also advise you to have a look at the page on other browsers, to make sure it's not a caching issue. Sometimes refreshing with F5 or CTRL+F5 still uses cached elements, which may not be up to date.

Comment: Nope, it all looks good to me.  I copied and pasted your file1.html and saw a 404 error with https://unpkg.com/purecss@0.6.2/build/grids-responsive-min.css, but it had a `space` in the URL that may be related to the SO editor, but otherwise your implementation is correct.

Comment: @arktoga Thanks for commenting! I've tried with Safari, Firefox, and Chrome and all are showing both css files actually (reset.css file **and** style.css) with the file2.html content.

Comment: Thanks @dereknutile for checking! Yeah I think that space isn't in the actual file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is within an express app and I hadn't served up my public folder so that it could use it to access static files.

Needed this:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public')));
```

Answer (score 2):

Your path seems to be right, but it could be because you are missing a closing quotation for your integrity attribute.

Comment: Thanks @sarahjee. I accidentally did that in the SO editor when I didn't want to take up an entire line with what is the actual attribute in my code. I'll fix it now.

Answer (score 0):

Your third link is missing a " after blahblahblah.
Try fixing that.

Comment: Thanks @marcelo. I accidentally did that in the SO editor, it's not missing in the actual code.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer. You're suggesting/directing rather than providing a definitive answer. You don't want to mark the question as answered when there's not a direct answer.